# Pandas: How to save each row of col1 to separate file, with row of col2 as filename?

Tags: python, pandas, export

I have a dataframe, `data`, with two columns: one for 'Content' and one for 'Title'. I am trying to export each row of column 'Content' to a separate .txt file and I would like the corresponding row of 'Title' to be the filename of this .txt file.

So far I have this, which works well for the Title part (every file has a different filename), but not for the Content part: every .txt file has the same content - that of the last row. How do I change it so that every .txt file has the right content?

```
file = 'C:/mallet/mydata/thesisarticles/{}.txt'

for row2 in data['Title']:
    for row in data['Content']:
        with open(file.format(row2), 'w') as f:
            f.write(str(row))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`iterrows`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html):

```
file = 'C:/mallet/mydata/thesisarticles/{}.txt'
for i, row in data.iterrows():
    with open(file.format(row['Title']), 'w') as f:
        f.write(str(row['Content']))
```

Alternative:

```
def f1(row):
    with open(file.format(row['Title']), 'w') as f:
        f.write(row['Content'])

data.apply(f1, axis=1)
```