# Python: writing file to specific directory

Tags: python

This is likely a fundamental Python question,  but I'm stumped (still learning). My script uses Pandas to create txt files from csv cells, and works properly. However, I'd like to write the files to a specific directory, listed as `save_path` below. However, my efforts to put this together keep running into errors.

Here's my (not) working code:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

save_path = "C:\users\name\folder\txts"

df= pd.read_csv("C:\users\name\folder\test.csv", sep=",")

df2 = df.fillna('')

for index in range(len(df)):
    with open(df2["text_number"][index] +  '.txt', 'w') as output:
        output2 = os.path.join(save_path, output) # I'm uncertain how to structure or place the os.path.join command.
        output2.write(df2["text"][index])
```

The resulting error is below:

```
TypeError: join() argument must be str, bytes, or os.PathLike object, not 'TextIOWrapper'
```

Thoughts? Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: output is your file stream, not your file path. You have to specify the location of your filepath, e.g. the df2["text_number"][index] +  '.txt' in your case.

Comment: can you tell me what are you trying to achieve from last 3lines? do you want to copy text from one file to other?

Comment: The script writes a txt file whose name is the cell value in the column "text_number" (text_0, text_1, etc) and whose contents are the cell value for the :column text".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first generate the file name and then open it in write mode to put the contents.

```
for index in range(len(df)):
    # create file name
    filename = df2["text_number"][index] +  '.txt'
    # then generate full path using os lib
    full_path = os.path.join(save_path, filename)
    # now open that file, dont forget to use w+ to create the file if it doesn't exist
    with open(full_path, 'w+') as output_file_handler:
        # and write the contents
        output_file_handler.write(df2["text"][index])
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work.
(But you might want to check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49153012/15873043))

```py
for index in range(len(df)):
    filename = df2["text_number"][index] + '.txt'
    fp = os.path.join(save_path, filename)

    with open(fp, 'w') as output:
        output.write(df2["text"][index])
```